# TCL tail file name

Tags: tcl, tail

I used the tail command to capture the name from a file name before the ".".
However, some of my files has name that looks like that (ie: abc.txt.gz).
I only want abc and not abc.txt. Please advise.

Current Output

---

main_name = abc.txt

What I want for final output:

---

main_name = abc

---

My script is as below:

````````
foreach xxx $filename {
      puts "main_name = [file rootname [file tail $xxx]]"
}
```````
````````

Comment: You can repeat the `file rootname` command until the output is the same as the input.

Comment: Can you please give example?

Answer (score 2):

Repeatedly running the `file rootname` command will remove an extension on every iteration. So by continuing that until the output is the same as the input, you know all extensions have been removed:

```
foreach name [glob *] {
    set tail [file tail $name]
    set root [file rootname $tail]
    while {$root ne $tail} {
        set tail $root
        set root [file rootname $tail]
    }
    puts "main name = $root"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach: since the "." is not platform specific:

```
foreach name [glob *] {
    set tail [file tail $name]
    set dotIdx [string first "." $tail]
    if {$dotIdx > -1} {
        set tail [string range $tail 0 $idx-1]
    }
    puts "main name = $tail"
}
```